# Get Chat Messages in Reverse Chronological Order

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to get the newest Chat Messages from the Live Streaming API. But I always get the oldest first. Can I get it in an Inverse Order? Is there a property I can set to achieve this?

Here is some example code:

```
    if ($_GET['action'] == "listchatmessages")
    {
        $htmlBody .= '<h1>Chatnachrichten</h1>';
        $broadcastsChatResponse = $youtube->liveChatMessages ->listLiveChatMessages (
        $broadcastItem['snippet']['liveChatId'], 'snippet');
        $myfile = fopen("chatmessages.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $count = 0;
        if ($_GET['search'] != "")
        {
        if (!empty($broadcastsChatResponse['items']))
            {
                foreach ($broadcastsChatResponse['items'] as $broadcastChatItem)
                {
                    if ($count < 200)
                    {

                        $broadcastsDetailsChatResponse = $youtube->liveChatMessages ->listLiveChatMessages (
                        $broadcastChatItem['snippet']['liveChatId'], 'authorDetails');
                        $broadcastDetailsChatItem = $broadcastsDetailsChatResponse['items'][0];

                            if ((preg_match('/'.$_GET['search'].'/',$broadcastChatItem['snippet']['textMessageDetails']['messageText'])) OR $_GET['search'] == 'all')
                            {
                                $message = $broadcastChatItem['snippet']['authorChannelId'].'_'.$broadcastDetailsChatItem['authorDetails']['displayName'].'_'.$broadcastChatItem['snippet']['textMessageDetails']['messageText']."\n";
                                $htmlBody .= '<li> Author: <a href="'.$broadcastChatItem['snippet']['authorChannelId'].'">'.$broadcastDetailsChatItem['authorDetails']['displayName'].'</a> schrieb: '.$broadcastChatItem['snippet']['textMessageDetails']['messageText'].'</li>';
                                $count++;
                                fwrite($myfile, $message);
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }


                $htmlBody .= '<h4> Alle Chatnachrichten empfangen (Anzahl der teilnehmenden Nahcrichten: '.$count.')</h4>';
            }
            else
            {
                $htmlBody .= '<p>Der Stream scheint nicht online zu sein</p>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $htmlBody .= 'Kein Suchwort. Nutze all um alle Nachrichten zu nehmen';
        }

        fclose($myfile);
    }
```

Comment: Hi ModdyLP, Welcome to stack overflow! At the moment, your question will be difficult to answer as you've not provide any example code you are working with - please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question as fully as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a parameter you can pass into your request to the  [`liveChatMessages/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) endpoint to return the newest messages first.

You will have to download all of the messages and sort them by the ISO 8601 formatted date under each chat message's [`snippet.publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#snippet.publishedAt).

I would also recommend you file a enhancement ticket to Google [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube) if you would like this feature implemented in the API.